# How to checked Asp Check box List Item using AJAX call jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using Asp Check Box List for multi selection of items. I am binding this Check box list on server side on page load even and now i am trying to check selected items on AJAX call. My web method returning `PlantCode` and `UserID` i want to checked my check box in such a way if return `PlanCode` will match with Existing  `PlantCode` then only item should be selected or else it should be remain unchecked. while binding Check Box List i am binding with both property `Value Field` as well as `Text Field` But the problem is when i am selecting with DOM its only returning `TextField` So i am not able to compare with value field.

**DOM**

```
<div id="checkboxplant" style="width: 100%; height: 150px; overflow: auto">
<table id="chkPlantsAddNew" class="MyClass" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_0" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$0"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_0">1001</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_1" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$1"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_1">CPP</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_2" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$2"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_2">BAKERY</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_3" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$3"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_3">Distribution</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="chkPlantsAddNew_4" type="checkbox" name="chkPlantsAddNew$4"><label for="chkPlantsAddNew_4">HQ</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
       </div>
```

As you can see no value field is append with check box list. Instead of one level has been  created dynamically with Same ID as check box list and Text appended to it. I am looking how can I am getting text of that label.

i.e `<label for="chkPlantsAddNew_0">1001</label>`  how to Get text as **1001**

I tried Like this :

**deptsSelected += $("label[for='" + PlantName + "']").text() + ',';** but no Success

AJAX Success Function

```
function OnSuccessRecordCall(data, status) {
                result = Record;
                var deptsSelected = '';
                if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {

                    var checkboxListS = $("[id*=chkPlantsAddNew]");

                    var PlantName = checkboxListS.innerText();

                    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxListS.length; i++) {
                        deptsSelected += $("label[for='" + PlantName + "']").text() + ',';
                       //alert(deptsSelected);
                       //var names = [];
                       // $('#chkPlantsAddNew input').each(function () {
                       //     names.push(this.name);
                       // });

                       // if (names == $.trim(result.PLANT_DESC_EDIT)) {
                       //     $(this).prop("checked", true);
                       // }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Where I am doing mistake kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use text(). Innertext is not a function.

```js
var checkboxListS = $("[id*=chkPlantsAddNew]");
console.log('checkboxListS', checkboxListS); // This gives you list with all checkboxes as array
var PlantName = checkboxListS.text();
console.log('PlantName', PlantName);
```

I don't know what are you doing. You need only the checked boxes?

```js
var deptsSelected;
var test;
$(checkboxListS).each( function( index, element ){
    console.log( $( this ).find('label').text());
    deptsSelected += $( this ).find('label').text();
});

console.log('deptsSelected', deptsSelected);
Output: 1001CPPBAKERYDistributionHQ
```

So you will get the text.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of

```js
console.log('checkboxListS', checkboxListS);
console.log('innerText', checkboxListS.innerText());
console.log('deptsSelected', deptsSelected)
```

Comment: for `console.log('deptsSelected', deptsSelected)` its simply returning of `,` it seems id are null

Comment: for `console.log('checkboxListS', checkboxListS);` its returning `checkboxListS n.fn.init(15)` which containing all related properties as i can see we have one property `Label` inside `Label` another property is there as name as `Innerhtml`

Comment: for `console.log('innerText', checkboxListS.innerText());`  I am getting error Like `Uncaught TypeError: checkboxListS.innerText is not a function`